# yum update error folowed with the python3 package error with same content

Tags: python-3.x, github, yum

yum -y update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#5 - "Could not resolve proxy: yourproxyserver; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
http://vault.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#5 - "Could not resolve proxy: yourproxyserver; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.

One of the configured repositories failed (CentOS-7 - Extras),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=extras ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable extras
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=extras

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=extras.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from extras: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://vault.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#5 - "Could not resolve proxy: yourproxyserver; Unknown error"